# dynamic_cast on polymorphic class copy segfaults

Tags: c++, copy, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

The following code snippet causes a segmentation fault during the `dynamic_cast`. Can anybody explain to me why this happens?

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

uint8_t buffer[32];

class Top {
public:
    virtual ~Top() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class Middle : public Top {
public:
    void copy() {
        // Create copy of class instance in buffer
        auto memory{reinterpret_cast<T *>(buffer)};
        *memory = *dynamic_cast<T *>(this);

        // Upcast, works
        Top * topPtr{memory};
        assert(topPtr != nullptr);

        // Downcast, causes segmentation fault, why?
        auto bottomPtr{dynamic_cast<T *>(topPtr)};
    }
};

class Bottom : public Middle<Bottom> {
};

int main() {
    Bottom b;   
    b.copy();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try debug the code? if you do `reinterpret_cast<T *>(buffer)`, then dereferencing is undefined behaviour because there is not `T` object there.

Comment: you're pointing a gun in your face and pulling the trigger, without knowing it. you can't cast memory allocated as an uint8_t[32] to an object, you are managing memory in the wrong way. reinterpret_cast is delicate and should be used with caution

Comment: I don't think it's the dynamic_cast but probably what is a call to a copy constructor. And I don't know why you're trying to do this, but this looks really really naughty.

Comment: @JosephLarson Not even a copy constructor, that's copy assignment which makes it worse.

Comment: Yeah. I shuddered as I tried to figure out what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
auto memory{reinterpret_cast<T *>(buffer)};
*memory = *dynamic_cast<T *>(this);
```

This is incorrect approach, you cannot just interpret some bytes as `T`. Objects are created only by calling the appropriate constructors which for example initialize the virtual jump table.

The second line is also wrong even in your context. It calls the assignment operator, that rightfully assumes its `this` is an alive object.

The correct way is using placement `new` with correctly aligned storage, for example `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)>`.

Working example:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>

class Top {
public:
    virtual ~Top() = default;
};


template <typename T>
class Middle : public Top {
public:
    void copy() {
        std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)> buffer;
        // Create a new T object. Assume default construction.
        auto* memory = new(&buffer)T();
        // Copy the object using operator=(const T&)
        *memory = *dynamic_cast<T *>(this);

        // Upcast, works
        Top * topPtr{memory};
        assert(topPtr != nullptr);
        // Downcast also works.
        auto* bottomPtr{dynamic_cast<T *>(topPtr)};

        // Using placement new requires explicit call to destructor.
        memory->~T();
    }
};

class Bottom : public Middle<Bottom> {
};

int main() {
    Bottom b;   
    b.copy();
}
```

- Lifetime begins with a constructor call, you cannot get around that, if it needs parameters, you have to pass them.
- `operator=` is the correct approach to copy objects, do not use `std::memcpy` unless you really know what you are doing.
- Objects created by placement new require explicit call to their destructor.
- Please do not hide pointers behind `auto`, `typedef`,or `using` with exception of opaque handles.

Comment: i think you should traduce your solution with std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)> into an example

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper I agree, done.